# Spotify- Does spotify api allows to save images temporarily

Tags: javascript, html, spotify

For my spotify application i want to store images of artists from last.fm temporaily on local storage.
Somebody can tell me is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible.
Use the HTML5 local storage api as mentioned in the Spotify Apps Guidelines.

Spotify Guidelines: http://developer.spotify.com/download/spotify-apps-api/guidelines
HTML5 Local storage: http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: Thanks Kristoffer, I know html5 storage api allows this but i want to store images locally at client side so that my spotify application will run faster.

Comment: So can't you do that with HTML5 local storage? Like this perhaps: http://geeknizer.com/cache-images-with-html5-local-storage/